# jQuery Select element by data value

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I was using the below code to select an element by data attribute value.

The HTML code is:

```
...
  <li data-conversation-id="2"></li>
...
```

And JavaScript code:

```
$li = $conversations.find("[data-conversation-id='" + conversation_id + "']");
```

I've updated my template code and conversation-id is now set on the element via `.data('conversation-id')` in jQuery rather than as an inline attribute.

The `.find()` selector no longer works.

Comment: can you please add a demo on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filter to check the attribute, but you'll need to select all children's. Having a selector to reduce the stack is needed for a performance gain. You can use something like this :

```
$li = $conversations.find("*").filter(function(){
    return $(this).data("conversation-id") == conversation_id;
});
```

Using `'[data-conversation-id]'` or `'li'` instead of `'*'` could be a good performance gain **if your elements always have that attribute or are an `li`**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` in combination with `.data()`

like

```
var li = $('li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('conversation-id') == conversation_id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.attr('data-conversation-id', yourId)` to set it as inline attribute and `.find(..)` call will work.

Also, you can `filter` the elements using `.filter` method:

```
var $li = $("li").filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('conversation-id') === conversation_id;
});
// Do something with $li
```

> ### [`filter(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)
>
> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.